# How to present multiple plots as members of two groups of plots with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I've got this data frame:

```
Patient Test1   Test2   Test3   Disease
1   10  12  10  no
2   12  2   13  yes
3   15  15  18  yes
4   8   9   10  no
5   7   8   7   no
```

Now I wish to create a plot of this data. The lines presenting patients 1,4 and 5 should all be blue, and the remaining should be red.

This was the optimal answer I was looking for back then:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- read.delim("test.txt")
m_mydata <- melt(mydata,id=c("Patient","Disease"))

ggplot(m_mydata, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = Patient, colour = Disease)) + 
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
```

Comment: You can create separate lines according Disease with `geom_line(aes(group = as.factor(Disease)))`. However, what exactly would you like to plot? What is on X-axis and what is on Y-axis?

Comment: The X axis will be intervalls of the ca. 1000 Tests that have been done, each looking at a different metabolite in the Urine. The Y axis will be the intensities as you can see them below Test1, 2 and 3.

Comment: You mention intervals but I am not seeing any. What variable defines them?

Comment: in this case I used the intervall [1,2,3] while the whole frame would be [1,2, ... ,1000]

Comment: So, the X-axis is from 1 to 1000 and Y-axis are values on Test, Test2, ..., Test1000?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: How would the final plot look like? Feel free to include an image of a hand sketch or a "paint" image.

Comment: google: "ggplot spaghetti" `>` go to images `>` go to site that has a image showing what you want `>` adapt the code to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to transform your data from short to long format:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("Patient", "Disease")) %>%
  rename(Tests = variable,
         Values = value)

   Patient Disease Tests Values
1        1       0 Test1     10
2        2       1 Test1     12
3        3       1 Test1     15
4        4       0 Test1      8
5        5       0 Test1      7
6        1       0 Test2     12
7        2       1 Test2     12
8        3       1 Test2     15
9        4       0 Test2      9
```

After this step, you can plot it, with X-axis being represented with Test1, Test2, ..., Test1000 and Y-axis with its corresponding values. Moreover, it is grouped according Patient:

```
df %>%
 melt(id.vars = c("Patient", "Disease")) %>%
 rename(Tests = variable,
        Values = value) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = Tests, y = Values, color = as.factor(Disease))) +       
 geom_line(aes(group = as.factor(Patient))) + 
 scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", "#ff000c"))
```

[image]

Comment: I have probably not asked my question correctly at all. Since there are five patients I would like to have 5 individual lines that overlap each other. Each line represents a patient. The lines that represent a patient that has the disease are red, the ones that represent healthy patients are black.

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was:

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(test,value, colour = disease)) +
geom_line(aes(group = as.factor(patient)))
```